Draw border to column on every side but in top Jetpack Compose
I have a Column with a border like this
Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .weight(1f)
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(
                    width = 2.dp,
                    color = colorResource(R.color.appGreen)
                )
        )

That adds border to every side but I don't want to have border on the top, only want it on bottom, left and right.
Something like this:

Hoe can I do this?? Thanks

The border modifier doesn't offer the flexibility to exclude specific sides. Instead, you can use drawBehind to draw lines on all sides except the top.
Here's the code for your scenario:
Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .height(100.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .drawBehind {
                val cap = StrokeCap.Round
                val color = Color.Black
                val strokeWidth = 2.dp.toPx()
                val halfStrokeWidth = strokeWidth / 2
                val width = size.width
                val height = size.height

                // Draw left line
                drawLine(
                    cap = cap,
                    color = color,
                    strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
                    start = Offset(halfStrokeWidth, halfStrokeWidth),
                    end = Offset(halfStrokeWidth, height - halfStrokeWidth),
                )

                // Draw bottom line
                drawLine(
                    cap = cap,
                    color = color,
                    strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
                    start = Offset(halfStrokeWidth, height - halfStrokeWidth),
                    end = Offset(width - halfStrokeWidth, height - halfStrokeWidth),
                )

                // Draw right line
                drawLine(
                    cap = cap,
                    color = color,
                    strokeWidth = strokeWidth,
                    start = Offset(width - halfStrokeWidth, halfStrokeWidth),
                    end = Offset(width - halfStrokeWidth, height - halfStrokeWidth),
                )
            }
    ) {
        // Your column content here
    }



Also you can try this, less code:

        Box(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().height(100.dp)) {
            HorizontalDivider(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.BottomCenter), thickness = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)
            VerticalDivider(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart), thickness = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)
            VerticalDivider(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterEnd), thickness = 1.dp, color = Color.Black)
        }


